# How to receive objects in index.html from admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

All bojects have been successfully save in admin dashboard but do not receive dynamic data in index.html page from admin dasboard.

```
**views.py**
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import home
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    homeobject = home.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'homes': homeobject})

**models.py**
class home(models.Model):
    HOME_CATEGORY = [
        ('SR', 'Service'),
        ('VL', 'Vlog'),
        ('CR', 'course'),
    ]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    home_category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=HOME_CATEGORY)





**index.html**
 {% for home in homes %}
  {{home}}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your view function name is defined as `home` and your model is named `home`

you define `home` as a function so when you go to access `home.objects` python does not see your model `home`  but the function `home`

Change the class name of model from `home` to `Home` and do migrations - migrate . Also don't forget to change in query `Home.objects.all()`

**index.html**

```
{% for home in homes %}
   <h1> {{home.title}} </h1>
   <p> {{home.description}} </p>
   <img src={{home.image.url}} />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not solved,error is 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Change the Model name to `class Home(models.Model):` and try . Also don't forget to edit `homeobject = Home.objects.all()` and `python manage.py makemigrations` `python manage.py migrate`